# How do I make a program know where it is?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to add a picture to my program but you need the directory for the picture for that (by my understanding). How do I make the program know where it self is and find the picture that I want to add. Note I can't set the directory to where it is on my computer as I want the program to be usable on other computers.

Comment: Unclear to me what you are asking, but you can just add an image into your project's resources and use it.  It gets compiled into the exe.

Comment: It sounds like you either want to use a relative path to a resource (which is easy -- that's what Lars is referring to), or you want your application to discover its own installation path. If that's not the case, please try to explain you requirement in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)`